# Bottom align 2 divs inside parent div (while keeping one child div on top of another child)

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I have 3 divs:

```
<div class="parent"> 
  <div class="child1"> </div>
  <div class="child2"> </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.child1, .child2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

I need to align `child2` div to be on bottom of `.parent` div, while `child1` div should be  ON TOP of `child2` div.

So, both `child1` and `child2` should be bottom aligned to the parent div, but `child1` should be on top of `child2`.

How can I achieve this? If there is only one child div - it can be achievable with setting `position: absolute; bottom:0`, but I cannot figure out if there are 2 child divs, and one child div should be on top of another.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Flexbox on `.parent` and apply the following styles:

```css
.parent {
  /* Introduce Flexbox */
  display: flex;

  /* Establishes the y-axis as the main axis.
     This displays the children from top to bottom */
  flex-direction: column;

  /* Packs the children from the end of the main axis */
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.child1,
.child2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.child1 {
  background: red;
}

.child2 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"> </div>
  <div class="child2"> </div>
</div>
```